# How many triangles can be made from 16 nails in a square?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations

$16$ nails placed at equal intervals in a shape of a square. Corner nails are shared, there are $5$ on each side. How many triangles can be formed when an elastic band is wrapped around $3$ or more of these nails? Count rotations and reflections separately?

I have tried using the addition principle (combinations and permutations).

$27\times 4=108$ triangles using intermediate nails on edges.

Taking $1$ corner nail and other $2$ intermediate nails we have$$4\times (3\times 3+2\times 3\times 6+3\times 5)=240.$$Taking $2$ nails from each side corner we have $4\times 9=36$ triangles from other intermediate nails.

Taking $2$ diagonal nails we have $2\times 12=24$ triangles from other intermediate nails.

Taking $3$ nails from the corner we have $4$ triangles.

Thus in total$$108+240+36+24+4=412$$triangles.

But I am not sure how to find triangles that are reflections/rotations of eachother.

(Sorry if the question is badly written I only joined today. Please let me know how I can fix the question.)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title... yours could apply to absolutely *ANYTHING*.

Comment: [You asked this question already.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4509824/409) Showing your work this time is quite welcome; but, instead of deleting-and-reposting, you should have simply edited your previous version. (Deleting the old version gives the appearance that you're trying to circumvent having been closed by the community, which is inappropriate.) Please remember this in the future. ... Good luck!

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know you could edit.

Comment: There's all sorts of ways to think of it.  The hard part would be taking into account that not all three vertices can be on the same side.  You can figure out all ways to connect three nails as subtract all the lie on the same line.  Or you can first select the one vertex that is not on the same side and calculate how to select two more that are not on the same line.

Comment: You identify this as a contest question.  What is the contest?  We want to be able to verify that it's not still an open contest.

Comment: Its a contest me and my friends had but one of my friends moved and we dont know how to contact him and he has all the answers so we decided to ask around on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an easier way to count triangles, if rotations and reflections are separate.  Any set of $3$ nails results in a triangle unless those nails are collinear.  The resulting triangles are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with non-collinear sets of $3$ nails.

There are $\binom{16}{3}=560$ combinations of $3$ nails with no constraints.  We have to subtract off collinear sets of $3$ nails.  There are $4$ different lines (each edge of the square) and for each line there are $\binom 53=10$ different combinations of $3$ collinear nails.  Thus, there are a total of $560-4 \cdot 10=520$ distinct triangles.